Por que el usuario es redirigido a signin despues de registrarse cuando debería ir a otra pagina- nextjs
Estoy haciendo una aplicación Next.js, estoy teniendo un problema al momento de registrar un usuario en /signup, pues si lo guarda a la base de datos pero no lo esta redirigiendo a su dashboard(en este caso /usuario), cabe aclarar que uso NextAuth ya que tambien tengo autenticación y/o agregación con google.
Paso a mostrar partes de los codigos donde creo que hay un problema que no encuentro
Lá pagina Signup
"use client"
import Link from "next/link"
import Image from 'next/image';
import CustomButton from '../../components/CustomButton';
import {signIn, useSession} from 'next-auth/react'
import { Navbar2 } from "@/components";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import React, {useState} from "react";
import CustomAlert from '@/components/CustomAlert';

export default function Form(){
    const router = useRouter();
    const { data: session, status: sessionStatus } = useSession();
    
    const handleSubmit = async (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const res = await fetch("/api/usuarios",{
            method: "POST",
            body: JSON.stringify(formData),
            headers:{
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            }
            
        })
        
        if(res.ok){
            router.replace("/usuario");
        } else {
            throw new Error("Error al crear el usuario")
        }
        
    }
    const handleChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) =>{
        const value = e.target.value;
        const name = e.target.name;
        setFormData((prevState) => ({
            ...prevState,
            [name]: value,
        }));
    }
    const startingUsuariosData={
        nombre: "",
        apellido: "",
        correo: "",
        contrasena: "",
        role: "usuario",
    };
   
    const [formData, setFormData] = useState(startingUsuariosData);
   

    export default function Form(){
        
        return(
            <>

La pagina Signin
"use client"
import Link from "next/link"
import Image from 'next/image';
import CustomButton from '@/components/CustomButton';
import {signIn, useSession} from 'next-auth/react'
import { Navbar2 } from "@/components";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import CustomAlert from '@/components/CustomAlert';

export default function Form(){
    // const session = useSession();
    const router = useRouter();
    const { data: session, status: sessionStatus } = useSession();
    const [alertMessage, setAlertMessage] = useState(""); // Mensaje de alerta
    const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (sessionStatus === "authenticated") {
        //router.replace("/usuario");
            if(session?.user?.role === "usuario"){
                router.replace("/usuario");
        }else{
            router.replace("/terapeuta");
        }}
    }, [sessionStatus, router]);

    const handleSubmit = async (e: any) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const email = e.target[0].value;
        const password = e.target[1].value;

        const res = await signIn('credentials', {
            email,
            password,
            redirect: false,
        });

        if (res?.error) {
            setAlertMessage("Contraseña y/o correo eléctronico incorrecto");
            setIsVisible(true);
        }
    };

    if (sessionStatus === "loading") {
        return <h1>Loading...</h1>;
    }

    return(
        <>

route.ts que se encarga de hacer el signin con google y tambien de su agregación a la base de datos
import NextAuth from 'next-auth'
import GoogleProvider from 'next-auth/providers/google'
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
import { connectDB } from "@/libs/mongodb";
import User from "@/models/usuarios";
import { GoogleProfile } from 'next-auth/providers/google';
import getServersession from 'next-auth';



const authOptions = {   //const handler = NextAuth({ -> lo que estaba antes
    providers: [ 
        GoogleProvider ({
        profile(profile:GoogleProfile){
            return{
                ...profile,
                role: "usuario",
                id: profile.sub,
            }
        },
        clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID as string,
        clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET as string,
        }),
        CredentialsProvider({
            id: 'credentials',
            name: "Credentials",
            credentials: {
              email: { label: "Email", type: "text" },
              password: { label: "Password", type: "text" },
            },
            
            async authorize(credentials: any) { //credentials: any

            {
              await connectDB();
              try {
                
                const user = await User.findOne({ correo: credentials.email });
                if (user && user.contrasena === credentials.password) {
                    // La contraseña coincide, puedes devolver el usuario
                   // console.log(user);
                    return user;
                } else {
                    // La contraseña no coincide
                    return null;
                }
              } catch (err: any) {
                throw new Error(err);
              }}  
            },
          })
    ],
    callbacks: {
        
        async signIn({user, account}: { user: any, account: any }) {
            if (account?.provider === 'credentials') {
                //console.log(user);
                return true;
            }
            if (account && account.provider === 'google') {
                const {name, email} = user;
                try {
                    const res = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/usuarios', { //http://localhost:3000/api/usuarios
                        method: 'POST',
                        headers: {
                            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                        },
                        body: JSON.stringify({
                            nombre: name,
                            correo: email,
                            role:  "usuario",
                        }),
                    });
                    if (res.ok) {
                        console.log(user)
                        return true;
                    }
                } catch (error) {
                    console.error(error);
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        },
         jwt({ token, user }: { token: any, user: any }) {
            // Persist the OAuth access_token to the token right after signin
            if (user) {
              token.role = user.role
            }
            //console.log(token);
            return token;
          },
           session({ session, token}: { token: any, session: any }) { //, user 
            // Send properties to the client, like an access_token from a provider.
            //session.accessToken = token.accessToken
            session.user.role = token.role
            //console.log(session);
            return session;
          }
        
        
    }
};
const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);
export {handler as GET, handler as POST};

Y route.js que hace la agregación normal a los usuarios que llenan el formulario
import { connectDB } from "@/libs/mongodb";
import  Usuarios from "@/models/usuarios";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

//Función GET para obtener todos los usuarios
export async function GET() {
    await connectDB();
    const usuarios = await Usuarios.find({});
    return NextResponse.json({ usuarios });
}


export async function POST(request) {
    await connectDB();
    const data = await request.json();
    const userExists = await Usuarios.findOne({ correo: data.correo });
    if (!userExists) {
        const usuarios = await Usuarios.create(data);
        return NextResponse.json({ usuarios });
    } else{
        //Si el usuario ya existe, no hace nada
        return NextResponse.json({ message: "Usuario ya existe" });
    }
}

export async function DELETE(request) {
    const id = request.nextUrl.searchParams.get("id");
    await connectDB();
    await Usuarios.findByIdAndDelete(id);
    return NextResponse.json({ message: "Usuario eliminado" });
}

